# ZF1 Plugins Equivalent in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

In ZF1 I used to use a ACL plugin to check if a user is trying to access a non-authorized controller via preDispatch method.

I need to do something similar in ZF2. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ZF2 hooks such as pre/post dispatch has been replaced with Events . The new MVC uses EventManager to fire MVC events such as dispatch .

In your Module.php add

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{

    $eventManager        = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,function(MvcEvent $event){
               //dispach code comes here
    });

}
```

Alternativly you can use prebuilt module for this purpose which also integrates with Zfc-User 
https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the code can simply goes in this lambda function? What if I have other plugins, all its code goes inside the onBootstrap method? It appears to me that ZF1 plugins are more semantically correct, separated in classes etc.

Comment: @rafaame It can be any of php callable types http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Comment: @rafaame All Modules `onBootstrap` will be called. All Events you attach there are grouped up into a priority Queue (u can set Priority for Events). That way you can make sure that your ACL Event will be called first and if that Event sends out a Response, all other Events will be stopped, as probably a new request is happening (like redirect to login page)